# secrets.yml when cloning, how to amke a new secrets.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, secret-key

Using Rails 4.1.1, I created a project.   Got it up and runnning, and now I want to share it with my research dev team.  Of course, the .gitignore hides the `secrets.yml` file from source control, but their versions won't run without their own version of a `secrets.yml` file, getting the following error:

> Unexpected error while processing request: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml

- Do we need to share the secret tokens?  (thus just copy and paste it over to their local machines)
- Should they be separate random keys? (What is the process when cloning a repo?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you should avoid storing private keys in source control, I would recommend that you instead add a **config/secrets.sample.yml** to your repository containing a template for the *secrets* like:

```
development:
  secret_key_base:
  some_random_key:

test:
  secret_key_base:
  some_random_key:

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SOME_RANDOM_KEY"] %>
```

Then you would just need to give them the values to fill in a secure way (voice, piece of paper, etc.)

There is an interesting blog post that you can read [here](https://intercityup.com/blog/deploying-app-env-variables-with-rbenv-passenger-and-capistrano/) about how to deploy your app's ENV variables.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without installing another moving part? I can't believe how hard it is to find one single clear instructions on how to use secrets.

Comment: Well handling credentials is sensitive, thus you should avoid adding your key to a source-control available to your whole team. There are plenty of blog-posts about it an none of them offers a perfect solution. Have a look at [this one](http://www.elabs.se/blog/57-handle-secret-credentials-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to share the secrets.yml keys and you can actually generate new secret keys using the following rake command:

`rake secret`

That should output a 128-digit pseudorandom hex value similar to this:

`b00dbff430b2c5596d10b3434ecd8a25515db481dccf818869a21d0c276ad159f00680aac38957ad57a73c9254754b32c42ef4fe2f76ee48d6e4ad8d4dc6a203`

Have each research dev team member run that command for each `secret_key_base` in the secrets.yml file.

---

If this is for a **production** environment, you'd want to set the value you get from `rake secret` into an environment variable.